# Access to not-public gcp storage through k8s ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, kubernetes-ingress

I want to ask how to define access to the storage bucket on gcp.
I have the configuration of my ingress because I want to have access to my file from the address myserver.com/assets/

My Config:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: google-storage-buckets-service
  namespace: myservice
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: storage.googleapis.com

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: assets-ingress
  namespace: myservice
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /bucket_name/$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: storage.googleapis.com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://myserver.com/auth/users/accessToken
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: Authorization
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: '*.myserver.com'
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/assets/(.*)"
            pathType: Prefix          
            backend:
              service:
                name: google-storage-buckets-service
                port:
                  number:
                    443
```

I know that with ingress I can check if a given person has access to this file using the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url` header.
However, if I understand it correctly, the given authorization service checks whether the person can log in and possibly passes the request further and we get the file as a response.

But for this to work, the bucket must be set to public, meaning there is a public URL where you can download this file without any problems and verification.

Can anything be done about it? I want to have no public access to my bucket, but I want to have still working ingress.

Comment: Under GKE Ingress feature, from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#feature_comparison), under feature comparison (Ingress Annotations) it will show you the available feature under ingress.

If we are talking about a feature on accessing your Cloud Storage, I would suggest “Signed URL” because of its security feature on how you can limit the access of a user to Cloud Storage. For more information your can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#overview).

Comment: Hi, is your post already resolved?